# How to refer to Excel index using Python Pandas ILOC?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

import re

file_name = "example.xlsx" #name of the excel file

sheet = "sheet" #name of the sheet

df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = sheet, usecols = "A:F") 

select_rows = df.iloc[516-2:] #specify rows
```

My question is why if I want to refer to row 516 onwards (from excel's index), I should subtract the number by 2 as stated on the code? I know the index on Pandas starting from zero, which means subtracted by 1 and not 2.

Answer (score 2):

@Samuel You are already 'minus one' because of zero-based index in Pandas. However, what isn't clear until reading the Pandas documentation for pd.read_excel is that there is a parameter called 'header' that is set to 0 by default (i.e. the first row (row 1 in Excel) is used as your header for column names). To demonstrate, try modifying the line where you create 'df' by adding an additional argument of header=None (code snippet below) and then run your code and inspect the results.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = sheet, usecols = "A:F", header=None)
```